# Facing CORS issue post implementing CSRF in spring 3.2.18 xml based application

Tags: spring, cors

My Application backend(Spring) and frontend(Angular) are running on different ports and backed running on HTTPS and front end on http.
I don't have any problem if i deploy both war's to any server. but when I am trying to communicate backend spring based application from angular front end at dev/local environment I am facing attached issue and i tried with different approaches like filter configurations at web.xml, at bean security xml level and tried with customized filter also, but i am unable to get rid of this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a7CN.png)

i tried with different approaches like filter configurations at web.xml, at bean security xml level and tried with customized filter also, but i am unable to get rid of this issue.

expecting solution which will support spring 3.2.18 xml configuration.